Inserting other mitzvot between loan-related commandments
In Berakhot 21b we learn that even those, who don't interpret the juxtaposition of different verses in the first four books of the Torah, they do so in the Book of Deuteronomy, because – as Ritva points out there among others – in Devarim Moses reiterated all the commandments he had heard from Hashem, so he consciously chose a logic order, which is not necessarily so in the previous books. Therefore, I found it unusual when I was reading Ki Teitzei that between two loan-related prohibitions (taking a millstone as a pledge and entering the house of a debtor) the prohibition of kidnapping and a reminder of tzaraat are interjected. I haven't seen Rashi commenting on this issue despite having done so a few verses earlier. Have you found any commentators discussing this seemingly strange insertion?

Very good q imo +1. This Malbim connects the two verses to each other, but not to the ones before and after: https://www.sefaria.org/Malbim%20on%20Deuteronomy%2024:7:1

The Even Ezra gives an explanation. He quotes others that say because of this question, that the first passuk refers to husband and wife and not a millstone. He then argues and explains differently:

כי נפש הוא חובל – כי בו מחית נפשות,
והסומכים על הסמך הפרשיות איננה טענה, כי כל מצו' עומדת בפני עצמה והסמיכות כדרך דרש. וזאת הפרש' דבקה, כי הזכיר שלא יגזול ענבים לתת אל כליו וחרמש בקמה, ולקחת אשה והיתה לו גם לאחר ויצא מרשותו, והלוקח אשה שישמח בה לא יהיה עשוק שיצא בצבא. וחביל' הרחים עושק וגם גונב נפש, וכן נגע הצרעת שלא ישמרו משפטיה תזיק הקרובים, וכן לא תעשוק העני בעבוטו והשכיר, והבנים הקטנים שלא ימותו בעון אביהם, והטיית משפט גר יתום וחבול בגד אלמנה, ושכחה בשדה כי היא לעני, וכן לא תעולל וכן פן יוסיף ונקלה, וחסימת השור עשק כי יגע ולא יאכל, והממאן ליבם כדמות עשק, והמחזקת במבושים עושקת, אבן ואבן איפה ואיפה עשק ממש, גם עמלק עשק לישראל:‏


For he taketh a man's life to pledge – For life is sustained by these instruments. Those who rely on the juxtaposition of the sections have no argument, (That our verse speaks metaphorically of sexual intercourse.) for each commandment stands by itself. (The commandments are not necessarily tied together. Each commandment is an independent unit.) The explanation of their juxtapositions is midrashic. (It therefore cannot be used as a reason to interpret a law metaphorically when the plain meaning of the text is acceptable.) This section (The law regarding taking a mill to pledge.) is connected to the previous ones in the following way: (That is, if we want to connect this section midrashically to what comes before, we can so in the following manner.) the Torah mentions that one is not to steal grapes by putting them in his pots (Deut. 23:25), or to lift up a sickle upon his neighbor’s grain (Deut. 23:26); or to take a woman after she has been his and then left his house and married another (v. 1). It also states that one has to cheer the woman whom he marries (v. 5); he is not to be oppressed by going into the army (Ibid.). The taking of a millstone in pledge is a form of oppression. (Hence the positioning of our law.) So too is kidnapping a person. Similarly the plague of leprosy, for if he does not observe its laws then the plague will injure those in proximity to it. (By infecting them.) Scripture similarly states, do not oppress a poor person by taking a pledge from him (v. 10). It similarly states do not oppress a hired person (v. 14) and small children should not be put to death for the sins of the fathers (v. 16). It likewise warns against perverting the justice due a stranger or the fatherless (v. 17). It prohibits the taking of a widow’s garment as a pledge (v. 17). It prohibits one from retrieving a sheaf which was forgotten in the field, for it belongs to the poor (v. 19). Similarly Thou shalt not glean (v. 21). Likewise lest if he should exceed…Then thy brother should be dishonored (Deut. 25:3). (Deut. 25:3 prohibits the infliction of more that 40 stripes to one being punished by lashes. Exceeding this number of stripes is a form of oppression.) The muzzling of an ox (v. 4) is an act of oppression, for the animal toils but cannot eat of its toil. Similarly, refusing to perform levirate marriage (Deut. 25:5-10) is a form of oppression. The woman who grabs a man’s testicles (Deut. 25:11) commits an act of oppression. Employing diverse weights and diverse measures (Deut. 25:13,14) is oppression in its purest form. Furthermore, Amalek oppressed Israel (Deut. 25:17-19). (Thus the laws in Deut. 23:25-25:19 are thematically related. Hence the law prohibiting the taking of a mill was included in this section.) (Sefaria)


Initially I couldn't parse the translation in you answer, because you didn't differentiate between the supercommentary and the words of Ibn Ezra. Now I get his point that oppression is the common motive that ties these commandments together. But it doesn't explain the strange order in my view.
